# How can I add a parallax effect into my side-scrolling game?

Tags: opengl, 2d, opengl-es

How can I add a parallax effect into my side-scrolling game? I read a lot about parallax scrolling so I know what the logic is and what parallax is but I can't create a dynamic parallax effect.

I have draw and update functions like this:

```
void UpdateBackground(Background &back)
{
    back.x += back.velX * back.dirX;
    if(back.x + back.width <= 0)
        back.x = 0;
}
void DrawBackground(Background &back)
{
    draw_bitmap(back.image, back.x, back.y, 0);

    if(back.x + back.width < WIDTH)
        draw_bitmap(back.image, back.x + back.width, back.y, 0);
}
```

So this draws a parallax effect with two background objects but it draws it statically. I'm creating a 2D side-scrolling game and I'm translating my character and my camera position along x axis. So I have to translate my parallax effect with my camera but when I add to background `position.x` it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parallax backgrounds are divorced from reality, you don't need velocities and directions.  What you do need is to base the background's X on the camera's position and modified with multiplier to offset the background more slowly so it looks like it is very far away.  Different layers of background can look closer by making this magic number bigger, so instead of 0.1f for far away use 0.3f for up close, etc...

An example might look like:

```
void UpdateBackground(Background &back, float cameraX)
{
    back.x = cameraX * 0.1f; // magic number to make the background move slowly
    back.x = fmod( back.x, back.width );
}
```

Comment: It seems this gonna work but it draws only one time.Any change in draw part of my code?Also i'm using java so can i use % instead of fmod ?

Comment: Yes, you can use float % float in Java for modulus.  I think what might be happening is that you need to draw the backgrounds directly as big bitmaps offset by the X, without the camera; since your camera is moving it's moving away from the backgrounds which are staying relative to 0.

Comment: So how can i achieve this?I have tried and searched a lot but i can't do it.

Comment: Cool option: If you move the background not slower, but at some speed in the opposite direction as the camera, you can create rotation rather than panning.

Comment: @DampeS8N How can i do this?Can you answer with code?

Comment: @droidmachine This isn't really a site where people write your code for you, that's your job. Patrick has given you the answer you requested, now it's up to you to implement it.

Comment: @Byte56 I know that but it's not clear.I'm searching for a tutorial about logic of that more than code.

Comment: @droidmachine You needn't go much further than [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling) to get the logic of parallax scrolling.

Comment: @PatrickHughes If you mean "don't translate your camera",i can't do that because i'm translating my character so i have to translate my camera also.